# Bootstrap grid not displaying rows

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am wanting to display images in a row for this portfolio, but they are displaying in a column. I can't seem to find anything that says I am doing this wrong. Any help with this?

Here is the code:

```
<div className="portfolio-wrapper">

        <div className="container">
            <h1 className="text-center py-5">
                Portfolio
            </h1>
            <div className="image-box-wrapper row justify-content-center">
                <div className="portfolio-image-box">
                    <img className="portfolio-image" src={autismapp} alt="Autism Therapy app..."></img>
                    <div className="overflow"></div>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon className="portfolio-icon" icon={faSearchPlus} />
                </div>
            
            {/*-*/}
            
                <div className="portfolio-image-box">
                    <img className="portfolio-image" src={rasp} alt="Raspberry Pi Card Scanner..."></img>
                    <div className="overflow"></div>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon className="portfolio-icon" icon={faSearchPlus} />
                </div>
            
            {/*-*/}
            
                <div className="portfolio-image-box">
                    <img className="portfolio-image" src={client} alt="Client Application..."></img>
                    <div className="overflow"></div>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon className="portfolio-icon" icon={faSearchPlus} />
                </div>
            
            {/*-*/}
            
                <div className="portfolio-image-box">
                    <img className="portfolio-image" src={server} alt="Server Application..."></img>
                    <div className="overflow"></div>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon className="portfolio-icon" icon={faSearchPlus} />
                </div>
            
            {/*-*/}
                
                <div className="portfolio-image-box">
                    <img className="portfolio-image" src={github} alt="Github Projects..."></img>
                    <div className="overflow"></div>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon className="portfolio-icon" icon={faSearchPlus} />
                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS styling on the classNames. I am not sure what would make them not show as a row, but it may seem that some of my end tags may be messed up. It is difficult to tell.

```
.portfolio-image{
width: 15rem !important;
height: 8rem !important;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid var(--primary-pink);
padding: 0 0.5rem;
}


.portfolio-image-box{
position: relative;
margin: 1rem;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The className "portfolio-image-box" needs to be "portfolio-image-box col" to be recognized as apart of the grid.  This is because columns are expected to be in rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention the CSS property you have applied on these className. Without these, it's difficult to find the issue.

I think the width of the inner div is set to 100%. Try to set the breakpoints and width of the image or the div.

Comment: I added the CSS to the post above, thank you, I will try setting the breakpoints and width of the image and will follow up.